# Is there any way to limit the selection of SelectItem in smartgwt?

Tags: smartgwt

I want to limit the check box selection of selectItem in smartGWT. My select item contains "n" number of options but the user wants to select only maximum of 7 options from the selectItem. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose from several ways to achieve this.

I would choose between these two options (depending on your application):

1. Add a [CustomValidator](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/validator/CustomValidator.html) to that Formitem. This validator should evaluate to false if the SelectItem contains as value a list with more than 7 elements. Note that such a Validator could transform the value of the item and that you could specify the error message next to the formitem.
2. Add a ChangeHandler (via addChangeHandler) to the FormItem and chancel ChangeEvents when more than 7 elements are selected (and provide a notification to the user).